# How do i format a date in Linq To Entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I need to format a datetime as a shortdatestring in my LINQ To Entities query.  I tried the following, but it does not work-

```
aryData =
(
    From cert In db.LWCerts _
    Select New With { _
       .ToBeProcessedDate = cert.ToBeProcessedDate.ToShortDateString 
    }
).ToArray()
```

How can I get a date to return as a short date string ("ie: 08/05/2013")?

EDIT Here is the entire linq query-

```
             aryData =
        (From lwl In db.LWCertLoans _
        Join c In db.Loans _
   On c.LoanNum Equals lwl.LoanNum _
   Join p In db.LWCertColls _
   On lwl.CertID Equals p.CertID _
   Join r In db.RespCntrs _
   On r.BranchNum Equals c.BranchNum _
   Join cert In db.LWCerts.AsEnumerable() _
   On cert.LWCertID Equals lwl.CertID _
   Where lwl.LoanNum = p.LoanNum _
   Select New With { _
       .ToBeProcessedDate = cert.ToBeProcessedDate, _
    .CertType = cert.CertType, _
    .CertCollID = p.CertCollID, _
    .CertificateID = p.CertID, _
    .LoanNumberTypeAndCurrencyCombined = c.LoanNum, _
    .LoanType = c.LoanType, _
    .CurrType = r.CurrType, _
    .CollanteralBalance = c.ColCurBal, _
    .SalesAdditions = p.Sales, _
    .CreditMemos = p.Credits, _
    .CashRemovals = p.NetCollect, _
    .NonDilutiveAdjustment = p.PlusAdj, _
    .Discounts = p.Discounts, _
    .NonARCash = p.NonARCash, _
    .DilutiveAdjustment = p.NegAdj, _
    .LWCertCollsComments = p.Comments, _
    .StatusCode = p.StatusCode, _
    .CertLoanID = lwl.CertLoanID, _
    .Modified = lwl.Modified, _
    .LoanNum = lwl.LoanNum, _
    .EffectiveDate = lwl.EffectiveDate, _
    .RepWireNumber = lwl.RepWireNumber, _
    .Advance = lwl.Advance, _
    .ModifiedDate = lwl.ModifiedDate, _
    .DDAAccountName = lwl.DDAAccountName, _
    .LWCertLoansComments = lwl.Comments, _
    .Comment = If(cert.CertType = 0, p.Comments, lwl.Comments)}).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `ToString` from database to application, using `AsEnumerable()`:

```
aryData =
(
    From cert In db.LWCerts.AsEnumerable() _
    Select New With { _
       .ToBeProcessedDate = cert.ToBeProcessedDate.ToShortDateString 
    }
).ToArray()
```

That will take `DateTime` as is is from database and then format it on application side.

Comment: I get the error "'ToShortDateString' is not a member of 'Date?'"

Comment: Try `ToString("d")` instead.

Comment: Now i get a different error - "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: So you haven't use `AsEnumerable` at all.

Comment: I posted the entire query in my edit above.  I added AsEnumerable to the lwcerts as suggested.  I have not used AsEnumerable in my class at all until now.  Could i be missing a import?